# Help in trying to make an Automator script .jpg Contact Sheet

Tags: macbook-pro, automator

So I have a friend who makes these nice contact sheets,
[image: image1]

by using FastStone Image Viewer 7.5 on a PC... I am on a Mac. Is there a way to take
.jpg files I have and run an automator script to make a .jpg contact sheet like similar to what he gets by using FastStone?  I see a script to make a .pdf, but I need the output to be .jpg format.  Trying to figure it out...

Any direction appreciated.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to add a step to the PDF script, converting it to a JPEG.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to figure out the conversion to .jpg and see a conversion option but am having trouble with the whole process and was looking for a little more input / direction / help.   I also cannot figure out how to use multiple images....  Its easier to use use .jpg's and not even bother with the .pdf but I keep my pictures outside of Photos.

Comment: There are plenty of apps that are designed to create contact sheets.

Comment: @benwiggy, care to provide some examples? Google mostly gives me stuff that disappeared in the past decade, or something that requires some Adobe app that I'm not going to buy.